# SQL Server Agent Jobs Log custom messages in Job History

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Is it possible to log custom messages from your SQL Server Agent job in the job history messages?
If not what's the best way to go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 7):

For T-SQL job steps, you can use the `print` statement.  For CmdExec steps, use `Console.Writeline` in your executable.  If there is a lot of output, then by default SQL Agent will not keep all of, and will only keep a certain number of characters.  To have it keep all output for a step, you go to the step properties, Advanced, and check the "Include step output in history" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it for a while, but I believe text generated by a PRINT statements in the code executed by the job will end up in the history table. If that doesn't work, RAISERROR with severity less than 11 should do it. (11 and up definitely will, but then jobs are marked as having failed.)